# Polynomial problem TUGMOs Grade9

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, roots

Let $a,b$ and $c$ be the three real roots of the polynomial $x^3-​5x^2​+5x+1=0$ 
find the value of
$(a^2​+ab+b^2)​(b^2​+bc+c^2)​(c^2​+ca+a^2)​$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Can You include Your attempt to solve it as well? People will be more willing to help

Comment: Hint: $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$.

Comment: @Cell Wall Nice problem! Show please your attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^3-5x^2+5x+1$, and note that any solution must satisfy the equation $$x^3=5x^2-5x-1 \tag{1}$$

Note $$\begin{align} \prod_{cyc}(a^2+ab+b^2) &=\prod_{cyc}\dfrac{a^3-b^3}{a-b} \\ &=\prod_{cyc} \dfrac{5a^2-5a-5b^2+5b}{a-b} \quad (\because (1))\\ &= \prod_{cyc} (5a+5b-5) \\ &= 125 \prod_{cyc} (4-c) \quad (\because a+b-1=4-c) \\ &= 125 f(4) =625\end{align}$$

Comment: $(4-a)(4-b)(4-c)$ is indeed equal to $5$ but this is not always equal to $f(4)$ (say, for other polynomials).

Comment: @TobyMak Well here $f(x)$ is a polynomial with a leading coefficient of $1$, and for any such polynomial it is true that $f(x)$ is equal to the product of $(x-\alpha_k)$ where $\alpha_k$ are the roots of $f(x)$ (counting multiplicity). So I don't think I understand your question.

Comment: Oh, okay I see what you mean.